# Why BitBlt does not copy the correct part

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

When I try to use the below code to copy the application icon to the client area's left top corner, I used code like below:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    hdcClient = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
    hdcWindow = GetWindowDC (hwnd) ;

    cxSource = GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSIZEFRAME) + GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSIZE) ;
    cySource = GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSIZEFRAME) + GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYCAPTION) ;

    BitBlt (hdcClient, 0, 0, cxSource, cySource, hdcWindow, 0, 0, SRCCOPY) ;

    ReleaseDC (hwnd, hdcWindow) ;
    EndPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
    return 0 ;
    ......
```

However what I always get is like this:

[image]

It seems what the hdcWindow get is the hdc of the window under it. I cannot figure out what is wrong with my BitBlt() call.

- I did it in Windows 7 box.

Comment: it all depends upon the `hwnd` being used. is it of the usable client area?

Comment: Try: BitBlt (hdcWindow, 0, 0, cxSource, cySource, hdcWindow, 0, 0, SRCCOPY) ;

Comment: Just use WM_GETICON and DrawIcon().

Comment: It would be helpful to me to know if you are trying to modify the example from Petzold's book *Programming Windows 5th edition* ?

Comment: Yes, I am modifying the example.

Comment: **Warn**: `0, 0, SRCCOPY);` is illegal for multi-montors on the left, use `GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN), SRCCOPY);` instead!

Answer (score 0):

```
hdcClient = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
hdcWindow = GetWindowDC (hwnd) ;

cxSource = GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSIZEFRAME) + GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSIZE) ;
cySource = GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSIZEFRAME) + GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYCAPTION) ;

BitBlt (hdcClient, 0, 0, cxSource, cySource, hdcWindow, 0, 0, SRCCOPY) ;
```

Here, the **destination** for the copy is the `hdcClient`, which is a handle given by `BeginPaint`. But `BeginPaint` returns handle to context of Client Area, which is not what you want. You want to write anywhere to the Window area (including over scrollbar/menus etc), so you probably want the destination to be hdcWindow.

Comment: Exactly, I want to copy it to my client area.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. So it's printing in the correct spot but not the full image you want, is that it?